# WPF How can a button in an ItemsControl operate independently from each other button in a custom expander?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create my own expander control.
It has a header and a body. The header is a button that shows or hides the body.
This is all in an `<ItemsControl/>` that is bound to an observable collection - Each object in the observable collection creates its own expander control.

For the most part, this is working. What I am having trouble with is the expanding part. When clicking on the header, all the controls show or hide their contents at the same time - I know what the problem is: All the properties are bound to a value at the same time. **How do I make them operate independently from one another?**

I am not even sure that the way I am trying to handle this is the best way (I could use the expander control but I am still learning WPF and XAML and would like to recreate some standard controls for practice and understanding). I am still trying to figure out how bindings work; mostly `RelativeSource` and everything associated with it.

I would also like to pass a selected object as a parameter through the `x:name="btn_body"` button.

My current XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding testName}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="parent" Margin="50,5" Background="Yellow"
                                Height="{Binding DataContext.ParentHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}">

                        <DockPanel x:Name="child_header" Height="50" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Aqua">
                            <Button Height="50" x:Name="btn_header"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCloseBoxCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text=" CONTENT "/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </DockPanel>

                        <DockPanel  x:Name="child_body" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                    Visibility="{Binding DataContext.Visable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}"
                                    Height="{Binding DataContext.ChildHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}">

                            <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Button x:Name="btn_body" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="35,5" Content="CONFIRM"/>
                            </Grid>

                        </DockPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The ViewModel for the above (DataContext is set in the MainWindow code behind)

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            string content = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\tempfiles\\people.json");
            var listOfPeople = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<apiResponse>(content);

            testName = new ObservableCollection<person>(listOfPeople.people);

            OpenCloseBoxCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenClose);
        }

        public RelayCommand OpenCloseBoxCommand { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<person> testName { get; set; }

        private int _parentheight = 150;
        public int ParentHeight
        {
            get { return _parentheight; }
            set { _parentheight = value; }
        }

        private Visibility _visable = Visibility.Visible;
        public Visibility Visable
        {
            get { return _visable; }
            set { _visable = value; }
        }

        private int _childheight = 100;
        public int ChildHeight
        {
            get { return _childheight; }
            set { _childheight = value; }
        }

        public void OpenClose()
        {
            if(_parentheight == 150)
            {
                _parentheight = 50;
                _visable = Visibility.Hidden;
                OnPropertyChanged("ParentHeight");
            } else
            {
                _parentheight = 150;
                _visable = Visibility.Visible;
                OnPropertyChanged("ParentHeight");
            }
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**

I have moved the properties over to the `person` class, along with the command. The general functionality works as expected now, but, **Is the following the correct way to do things?**
I understand the idea behind the MVVM pattern and as such I am trying to keep the UI stuff away from everything else as what I am trying to achieve is purely UI logic and non critical to functionality (this expander could be replaced by a grid and everything would function normally).

It just seems that UI "logic" is creeping into where it shouldn't be.

```
public class person : ViewModelBase {    //needed for OnPropertyChanged

        public person()
        {
            OpenCloseBoxCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenClose);
        }

        public RelayCommand OpenCloseBoxCommand { get; set; }

        public string PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string SecondName { get; set; }

        private int _parentheight = 150;
        public int ParentHeight
        {
            get { return _parentheight; }
            set { _parentheight = value; }
        }

        private Visibility _visable = Visibility.Visible;
        public Visibility Visable
        {
            get { return _visable; }
            set { _visable = value; }
        }

        private int _childheight = 100;
        public int ChildHeight
        {
            get { return _childheight; }
            set { _childheight = value; }
        }

        public void OpenClose()
        {
            if (_parentheight == 150)
            {
                _parentheight = 50;
                _visable = Visibility.Hidden;
                OnPropertyChanged("ParentHeight");
            }
            else
            {
                _parentheight = 150;
                _visable = Visibility.Visible;
                OnPropertyChanged("ParentHeight");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could create a "wrapper" class around a person which contains the person and a `visible` property

Answer (score 1):

ParentHeight and Visable should be property of person,not MainWindowViewModel.
In addition, as a member of MainWindowViewModel,OpenCloseBoxCommand should be added a parameter for pass current item.

I want to know why do not you choose Expander control?
I ever implemennt a Expander in Listbox,it worked well.

Comment: Your suggestion helped, see edit, thanks. I'm doing it this way to help better my understanding on how WPF works.